# Why does scala allow concating Strings with Option[Strings](or any other type)?

Tags: scala

I mistakenly concatted a string with an Option[String] while coding in scala.
I expected as a strongly typed language, scala would not allow me to do such operation.
This is what I tried.
This works

```scala
scala> val a:String = "aaa"
val a: String = aaa

scala> val b:Option[String] = Some("bbbb")
val b: Option[String] = Some(bbbb)

scala> a + b
val res0: String = aaaSome(bbbb)

scala> val c:Option[String] = None
val c: Option[String] = None

scala> val d = a + c
val d: String = aaaNone

scala> val e = 1
val e: Int = 1

scala> a + e
val res2: String = aaa1
```

while this does not work

```scala
scala> val f:Option[String] = Some("ffff")
val f: Option[String] = Some(ffff)

scala> val g:Option[String] = None
val g: Option[String] = None

scala> f + g
           ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Option[String]
        required: String
```

Why does scala allow such behavior? Dynamically typed languages like python will stop me from adding strings to int types, None types or any type other than strings. Curious if this design is intentional? If so why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala contains an implicit class `any2stringadd` in it's `Predef` package. This class is responsible for these concatenation operations.

```scala
implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
}
```

What it means is that, by default, scope contains a method `+` which can concatenate value of any type `A` with string by converting value of this type to string via `String.valueOf(...)`.

I can't speak of design choices, I agree that this might be an unexpected behavior. The same applies to Scala's native `==` method. For example, this code compiles just ok: `Some("a") == "b"`. This can lead to nasty bugs in filtering and other methods.

If you want to eliminate this behavior I suggest you take a look at https://typelevel.org/cats/ library, which introduces different typeclasses that can solve this problem.

For example, for string concatenation you can use Semigroup typeclass (which has tons of other useful use-cases as well):

```scala
import cats.Semigroup

Semigroup[String].combine("a", "b") // works, returns "ab"
Semigroup[String].combine("a", Some("b")) // won't work, compilation error
```

This looks tedious, but there is a syntactic sugar:

```scala
import cats.implicits._
"a" |+| "b" // works, returns "ab"
"a" |+| Some("b") // won't work, compilation error
// |+| here is the same as Semigroup[String].combine
```

The same thing applies to `==` method. Instead you can use `Eq` typeclass:

```scala
import cats.implicits._
"a" == Some("b") // works, no error, but could be unexpected
"a" === Some("b") // compilation error (Cats Eq)
"a" === "b" // works, as expected
"a" =!= "b" // same as != but type safe
```

Comment: `any2stringadd` works for `AnyVal` + `String`, but in case of `a+b` `b` is `Option[String]` not `String`. If you try to run `b + a` against `2.13.3` version you will get `method any2stringadd in object Predef is deprecated (since 2.13.0)` while `a + b` still works.

Comment: I think https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6315 explains why it works like that.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into cats, and study scala more... any2stringadd looks really interesting!